# Shiny datatables: no funciona "$('select').on('change', function() {"

Tags: jquery, r, callback, shiny

Tengo un problema con el siguiente código: una columna de un datatable tiene varios select o listas desplegables, pero a la hora de ejecutar el código en el callback de JS no llama a la función $('select').on('change')... Puedes seleccionar pero no muestra el alert que quisiera. Esto es el comienzo de otro problema que tengo, pero quisiera ver si me pueden ayudar.

Este es el server.ui

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

input_data <- data.frame(Brand = c("Brand1", "Brand2","Brand3","Brand4", "Brand5","Brand6"),
                         ratio = c (.5, .5, .5, .5, .5, .5),
                         cost = c(2000, 3000, 4000, 2000, 3000, 4000),
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 
  
 

select = "<select><option>Uno</option><option>Dos</option><option>Tres</option></select>"
input_data$seleccion = select

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- input_data
  output$mod_table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data, 
                  selection = "none",
                  escape = FALSE,
                  options = list(pageLength = 5),
                  callback = JS(c(
                                  
                    "$('select').on('change', function() {",
                    "alert('seleccion realizada');",
                    "});"
                    
                  )))
    
  })
  

}
```

Y este es el ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(

    mainPanel(
      
      dataTableOutput("mod_table")
      
    )
)
```

Comment: como cargas el datatable con ajax o html puro y duro???

Comment: no se si te has pecatado pero cuando usas ajax para renderizar algo ... esos elementos no forman parte del DOM exactamente... entonces en jquery tienes que usar un metodo delegado para poder ejecutar los eventos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestros comentarios. Pero de entrada el datatable lo he hecho a mano directamente, sin usar ajax. El tema es que el cuando seleccionas un valor no salta el alert.

Comment: ¿hasm mirado si la consola muestra algun error cuando ejecutas la acción?  ¿tienes el jquery bien cargado previamente?

Comment: En ppio lo he mirado bien. De todas formas, lo que ocurre es que con un proyecto mucho más grande, el "$('select').on('change', function() {", funciona bien pero solo para la primera página del datatable, pero no ocurre así con las siguientes páginas. ¿Alguien sabe a qué puede deberse? Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Para detectar un cambio en el select de tu aplicación puedes usar un callback como el siguiente:

```
 callback = JS(c(                                  
                    "table.on('change', 'td:nth-child(5)' , function() {",
                    "alert('seleccion realizada');",
                    "});"                    
                  )))
```

En este caso `table` es el objeto regresado por `$( selector ).DataTable();` que se meciona en el [api de datatables](https://datatables.net/reference/api/). Te sugiero revisar esta pagina para conocer la funciones que puedes usar en el `callback`.